# Sorting multi dimentional array with value inside another array in laravel 6 - php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel-6

I want to sort the below array with the value of 'fee_category'. The first key of the array is date and inside each date it may contain multiple fees as in the 4th and 5th dates (which is [2020-10-15] and [2020-10-14]). I just need a simple way to get this sorting done. I tried usort(), but didn't work as expected.

```
Array(
    [2020-10-19] => 
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 2650
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
    )
    [2020-10-17] => 
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 630
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
    )
    [2020-10-16] => 
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 800
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
    )
    [2020-10-15] => 
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 550
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 550
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [2] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 2650
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
        [3] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 3850
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
        [4] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 630
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
    )
    [2020-10-14] => 
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 550
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 2650
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
        [2] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 550
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [3] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 1325
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
        [4] => Array(
            [fee_fare] => 550
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [5] => Array([fee_fare] => 800
            [fee_category] => Special Fee
        )
        [6] => Array([fee_fare] => 2700
            [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
        )
    )
)
```

expected output

```
Array(
[2020-10-19] => 
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 2650
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
)
[2020-10-17] => 
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 630
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
)
[2020-10-16] => 
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 800
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
)
[2020-10-15] => 
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 550
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 550
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [4] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 630
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 2650
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 3850
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
)
[2020-10-14] => 
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 550
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 550
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [4] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 550
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [5] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 800
        [fee_category] => Special Fee
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 2650
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [fee_fare] => 1325
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
    [6] => Array([fee_fare] => 2700
        [fee_category] => Tuition Fee
    )
)
```

)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your attempt and explain in what way it didn't give you the results you desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php) combined with [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)

```
$arr = [
    '2020-10-19' =>
        [
            0 => [
                'fee_fare' => 2650,
                'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
            ]
        ],
    '2020-10-17' =>
        [
            0 => [
                'fee_fare' => 630,
                'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
            ]
        ],
    '2020-10-16' =>
        [
            0 => [
                'fee_fare' => 800,
                'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
            ]
        ],
    '2020-10-15' =>
        [
            0 => [
                'fee_fare' => 550,
                'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
            ],
            1 => [
                'fee_fare' => 550,
                'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
            ],
            2 => [
                'fee_fare' => 2650,
                'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
            ],
            3 => [
                'fee_fare' => 3850,
                'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
            ],
            4 => [
                'fee_fare' => 630,
                'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
            ],
        ],
    '2020-10-14' => [
        0 => [
            'fee_fare' => 550,
            'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
        ],
        1 => [
            'fee_fare' => 2650,
            'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
        ],
        2 => [
            'fee_fare' => 550,
            'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
        ],
        3 => [
            'fee_fare' => 1325,
            'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
        ],
        4 => [
            'fee_fare' => 550,
            'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
        ],
        5 => [
            'fee_fare' => 800,
            'fee_category' => 'Special Fee'
        ],
        6 => [
            'fee_fare' => 2700,
            'fee_category' => 'Tuition Fee'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($arr as $key => $a){
    array_multisort(
        array_column($a, 'fee_fare'),
        SORT_ASC,
        $a
    );
    $arr[$key] = $a;
}



echo "<pre>";
echo "<b>".__FILE__."</b><br/>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Otput is :

```
array (size=5)
  '2020-10-19' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 2650
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
  '2020-10-17' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 630
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
  '2020-10-16' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 800
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
  '2020-10-15' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 550
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 550
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 630
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 2650
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 3850
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
  '2020-10-14' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 550
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 550
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 550
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 800
          'fee_category' => string 'Special Fee' (length=11)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 1325
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 2650
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
      6 => 
        array (size=2)
          'fee_fare' => int 2700
          'fee_category' => string 'Tuition Fee' (length=11)
```

As you can see we loop through the "main" array, splitting it to $key => $value, then we use array_multisort on the sub-array by the value of 'fee_fare' column